# Route Inspection Problem

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

The route inspection problem, is to find a shortest closed path that visits every edge of a connected undirected graph.

If $G = (V,E)$ is a tree, then any route inspection tour has $2\vert E\vert$ egdes in it (counted with multiplicity).

I would like to show that if $G$ is not a tree, then a route inspection tour has at most $2\vert E\vert - 1$ edges (or maybe even less). I assume this has to do with the fact that $G$ has in this case a cycle, but I cannot find the correct argument.

Comment: Sorry about my first post. Being more cautious now, I'll start this off as a comment: how about $K_{3,2}$?

In producing the optimal solution as on the Wikipedia article for the CPP, we have to double all edges, as every edge is incident to a vertex of odd degree, but no two odd vertices are actually adjacent, so we really have $2\#E$ edges to cover, and this graph has a cycle.

Comment: I find a tour with $7$ edges. I admit that I don't find the wikipedia article super clear...

Comment: If the graph has a $k$-cycle, then you can get down to $2|E|-k$ by deciding that the edges in the cycle are going to be used one each, and the rest of the edges covered by tree-shaped excursions from that cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do induction over the number of edges $m$:

For the induction step $m \rightarrow (m+1)$, consider something like this:

Let $G$ be any non-tree connected graph on $n$ vertices and $m+1$ edges. Because $G$ is not a tree, we can find an edge $e = \{u, v \}$ which does not destroy connectivity if we remove it. Now me remove this edge from $G$ and obtain a graph $G*$ with only $m$ edges.

There are now two cases:

1) $G*$ is not a tree. By induction hypothesis there is a postman tour on $G*$ with at most $2m - 1$ edges. Now we consider this tour in $G$. It covers all edges but $e$. Hence we obtain a postman tour for $G$ by simply adding it twice into the postman tour for $G*$. This postman tour for $G$ now has at most $2m - 1 + 2 = 2(m+1) - 1$ edges. (Actually this might not be a true postman tour for $G$ because it might not be the shortest possible. But this still proves that a postman tour for $G$ cannot have more than $2(m+1) - 1$ edges.)

2) $G*$ is a tree. Then we know that there is a postman tour for $G*$ with exactly $2m$ edges. Consider now this postman tour on $G$. It covers any edge but $e$ exactly twice. In particular, written in terms of nodes it looks like this: $ (u, ... , v, ... , u)$. Because all edges between $u$ and $v$ are covered twice, we can remove them once and replace them with the edge $e$. We obtain a postman tour $ (u, v, ... , u)$ with at most $2*m + 1 = 2(m+1) - 1$ edges.

Hope this helps. If you don't get what I am trying to do just ask again, I had quite some trouble explaining the second case.

Comment: In 2) I don't understand what "remove them once and replace them with the edge $e$" means.
Does it also means that we cannot do better than $2\text{Card}(E)-1$ in case of a non tree? Do you see a graph for which this is reached?
Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Ok, so what I mean by that is the following: you have a tour $t$ through all edges and therefore through all nodes. So on your tour $t$ you come by the node $u$, then you go on and eventually come by the node $v$ and then continue and eventually get back to $u$. The goal is now to build a new tour $t$ which contains also the edge $e$. To achieve this, you go along the tour $t$, come along $u$ and then along $v$. But now instead of following $t$, you go from $v$ directly back to $u$ using edge $e$. This you define as your new tour. It covers all edges.

Comment: Actually I didn't find any example where this is reached. I guess you could prove that for a non-tree the upper bound is $2Card(E) - 3$. When you modify the tour in case 2) you actually add one edge but remove at least two others. So the there the length is at most $2*m - 1 = 2(m+1) - 3$.